# How to change link of an uploaded file to the media library

Tags: permalinks, pdf

My client wants a PDF to be linked from a page with a different link structure.

Currently I have it set up so the path to the document is this

site.com/wp-content/uploads/date/PDF.pdf

What they want is site.com/specificpage/PDF.pdf

Could anyone provide any help on this?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about menus and your theme uses the Menu API, then upload the PDF to a publicly accessible server-- doesn't have to to be the one your site uses-- then

```
 go to Appearance -> Menus,
 Navigate to a menu, or create one
 find the "Links" dialogue,
 input the URL and the link text
 Save
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should've been more specific. I mean that they are linking to a PDF within text. So there're a hyperlink that goes to the PDF. They want the URL to be less "messy". Is what you're suggesting appropriate for this?